# How to create a php file dynmically in a particular folder in php?

Tags: php

Can anyone suggest how to create a php file dynamically in a folder where the file name can vary according to the user in php ?

Comment: you can write to the file like $my_file = 'file.txt';$handle = fopen($my_file, 'w') or die('Cannot open file:  '.$my_file);$data = 'This is the data';fwrite($handle, $data); also change the name dynamically as per the user in the session. Check if file is already there before creating again using file_exists function

Comment: Why do you want the name to be dynamic? Can't you include a "generic" file with all data?

Comment: try this http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_create.asp

Answer (score 0):

Try below code in PHP:

`file_put_contents($fileName,'')`

This will create a file with the given name. File name can be taken anything for example a username

Answer (score 0):

It's just as creating a text file, except you define the content.

```
$fileName = "X"; // Whereever you fetch the user input
$phpFile = fopen('./path/to/' . $fileName . 'php', "w") or die("Could not open file.");
$phpContent = "Your content";

fwrite($phpFile, $phpContent);
fclose($phpFile);
```